# same SHA1 hash for different strings

Tags: c, hash, openssl, sha1

I try to read content from different files, calculate their sha1, and compare it to a previously calculated hash to know if the content got modified.
I have a problem: sometimes when I calculate the sha1 hash I get the same hash for completely different content.
I have a file with url written in it. I read an url, then get the stored checksum from an hashtable I have for his last known content. I get his content using the function read_file, I calculate the hash for the current content and compared the 2 hashes.

Code executed in the main :

```
GHashTable *table = loadChecksums("checksums.txt"); //here i load some checksums i calculated before and stored
char *result=malloc(SIZE_MAX_URL*sizeof(char));
for(int i=0; i<SIZE_MAX_LIST; i++){
  if(fgets(result, SIZE_MAX_URL, fichier_url)!=NULL) {
    char *aux=strchr(result,'\n');
    aux[0]='\0';
    // i get the url from the file, now i read the coontent
    char *contenu = read_file(result);
    //get previously calculated hash to compare it with the one we will calculate
    char *hash = g_hash_table_lookup(table, result);
    unsigned char hashCalc[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    printf("Contenu: %s\n",contenu); // just to check it is the content i expect from the file
    SHA1(contenu, sizeof(contenu)-1, hashCalc); // calculate hash
    char *hexHash = toHex(hashCalc); // turn it into hex

    if(compareHash(hexHash,hash)){ // nothing changed
      printf("Le site n'a pas changé\n");
    }else{// content changed : i update my hashtable
      printf("Checksum different\n");
      g_hash_table_insert(table,g_strdup(result),g_strdup(hexHash));
    }
  }
}
```

hash functions

```
int compareHash(char *hash1, char* hash2){
  if(hash1 == NULL || hash2 == NULL){
    return 0;
  }
  for (int i = 0; i < 40; i++){
    if(hash1[i] != hash2[i]){
      return 0;
    }
  }
  return 1;
}

char * toHex(unsigned char*hash){
  char *hashHex = malloc(41);
  for(int i = 0 ; i < SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH ; i++){
    sprintf(hashHex+(i*2),"%02x",(unsigned char)hash[i]);
  }
  hashHex[40]='\0';
  return hashHex;
}
```

1st file i use as example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Test8</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test1</p>
    <p>Tesythythytht2</p>
    <p>Test3</p>
    <p>Test4</p>
</body>
</html>
```

2nd file :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Test5</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>Test16518489498</p>
    <p>Test2</p>
    <p>Tetyhtyhtyhst3</p>
    <p>Test4</p>
    orejgioejgiojeoijgreoigjeoij
</body>
</html>
```

With this code and these example, I get the following hash for both :

```
7a820ae07b87e220980556ea12d79e65eb3c19d3
```

Does anyone see where I'm doing something wrong? 
Thank you for your help.

PS: I don't know if I put too much information or too little on this post, sorry if this is not clear.

Comment: Too little. I can't compile your code and try it myself. See [mcve].

Comment: you have `char *contenu`, when you use `sizeof(contenu)` later, it is just the size of a pointer, not the length of your file, right?

Comment: Please post links to your files.

Comment: My code source files ?

Comment: As @tiwo suggests, you are actually hashing the 7 bytes `<!docty` in both cases. If your files are valid C strings (many files aren't) you could use `strlen`.

Comment: You're right that's exactly the problem, i corrected it and everything works. I feel a bit stupid now ! Thanks a lot !